# Is it possible to add an logo as mark to html5 video player on iphone ios / android

Tags: android, ios, html, html5-video

I want to add an logo as mark (on the right bottom side) to an video on IOS or android but not into the video. I want add the logo as overlayer.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

That's possible using an overlay (div) element on top of the video element. For instance, the guys from [dash-player.com](http://www.dash-player.com/) are doing that. Just have a look into their DOM. The only limitation (to the best of my knowledge) is fullscreen playback on an iOS device, where no overlays are possible.